# JavaFX is there any color gradient editor control?

Tags: javafx

For an editor that can map a Noise Function (-1 to 1 values) to Colors I need some Control that lets me define a Color Gradient, so something like
Value 
- 0 is black
- 0.3 is yellow
- 0.8 is red
- 1 is white
so the whole gradient goes from black to white and thats editable,
is there anything like that built into JavaFX or do I have to write my own Control?

Basically smth like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Scene Builder has a powerful gradient editor that allows inserting multiple stops:

[image: Scene Builder]

The control is called `PaintPicker`, and it is part of the Scene Builder Kit that you can download from [here](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/#download).

Once you have the jar, you can use the component.

This is a short snippet to show how to easily add it to your scene:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    PaintPickerController controller;
    final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(PaintPicker.class.getResource("PaintPicker.fxml")); 

    try {
        final VBox picker = loader.load();
        controller = loader.getController();
        controller.paintProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> System.out.println("Paint: " + nv));
        root.getChildren().add(picker);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 600);

    primaryStage.setTitle("SceneBuilder PaintPicker");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

[image: Paint Picker]

With the listener, you will get immediately the gradient:

```
Paint: linear-gradient(from 60.096% 38.461% to 47.115% 45.192%, 
    reflect, 0xda7777ff 0.0%, 0x226621ff 28.667%, 0xf2ff1cff 49.333%, 
    0xff1c5fff 73.0%, 0xffffffff 100.0%)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a [ColorPicker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ColorPicker.html).

[image]

More information on how to use it is on [JavaFX tutorials page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/color-picker.htm#BABHFGHA).

Comment: I need multiple Colors per Gradient, thats my problem, with the Color Chooser I can only select 1 Color

Comment: I don't understand. Your pic for the control shows something very similar to a Color picker.

Comment: No It has multiple Thumbs, so one can define that the Gradient goes from Red to yellow then to black then to white or something like that

Comment: Can't you do the same in the custom color dialog window?